# How do I do Python re.search substrings with multi-character wildcard?

Tags: python, regex, string, substring

I'm trying to extract a substring from a string in Python.
The front end to be trimmed is static and easy to implement, but the rear end has a counter that can run from "_0" to "_9999".

With my current code, the counter still gets included in the substring.

```
import re

text = "fastq_runid_0dc971f49c42ffb1412caee485f8421a1f9a26ed_0.fastq"

print(text)
substring= re.search('runid_(.*)_*.fas', text).group(0)

print(substring)
```

Returns

> 0dc971f49c42ffb1412caee485f8421a1f9a26ed_0.fas

Alternatively,

```
substring= re.search(r"(?<=runid_).*?(?=_*.fastq)", text).group(0)
```

returns

> 0dc971f49c42ffb1412caee485f8421a1f9a26ed_0

Works better but the counter "_0" is still added.

How do I make a robust trim that trims the multi-character counter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your regex `(?<=runid_).*?(?=_*.fastq)` there is a little problem. You have written `_*` which means zero or more underscores which will make underscore optional and will skip it matching and your `.*?` will eat `_0` too within it which is why in your result you get `_0` too. I think you meant `_.*` and also you should escape the `.` just before `fastq` so your updated regex should become this,

```
(?<=runid_).+(?=_\d{1,4}\.fas)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Qi9WP6/3)

Your updated python code,

```
import re

text = "fastq_runid_0dc971f49c42ffb1412caee485f8421a1f9a26ed_0.fastq"

print(text)
substring= re.search('(?<=runid_).+(?=_\d{1,4}\.fas)', text).group(0)

print(substring)
```

Prints,

```
0dc971f49c42ffb1412caee485f8421a1f9a26ed
```

Also, alternatively, you can use a simple regex without lookarounds and capture the text from first group using this regex,

```
runid_([^_]+)(?=_\d{1,4}\.fas)
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Qi9WP6/4)**

Your python code with text picking from `group(1)` instead of `group(0)`

```
import re

text = "fastq_runid_0dc971f49c42ffb1412caee485f8421a1f9a26ed_0.fastq"

print(text)
substring= re.search('runid_([^_]+)(?=_\d{1,4}\.fas)', text).group(1)

print(substring)
```

In this case too it prints,

```
0dc971f49c42ffb1412caee485f8421a1f9a26ed
```

Comment: You are not accounting the counter size, and therefor it's less strict.

Comment: I've extended and corrected OP's regex and I think OP just wants to get rid of `_somenumber` in his expected output. Although yes he told that number will range from 0 to 9999 but unless he has any text where numbers are larger than that, that hint is really not needed.

Comment: It could be that the strictness is not required in his case, but if he knows the exact format, no point to make it less strict. It's not a point to write pattern as small as possible, but to stick to the rules we got and have as less as possible mistakes. You are not even accounting that there are digits after _

Comment: Ok Boy, Your suggestions incorporated :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need look behind and look ahead to achieve that.

`\d{1,4}` means `min 1` `max 4` digits, otherwise it wont match

```
fastq_runid_(.+)_\d{1,4}\.fastq
```

https://regex101.com/r/VneElM/1

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

text = "fastq_runid_0dc971f49c42ffb1412caee485f8421a1f9a26ed_999.fastq"

print(text)
substring= re.search('fastq_runid_(\w+)_(\d+)\.fastq', text)

print(substring.group(1), substring.group(2))
```

`group(1)` will give what you want, `group(2)` will give the counter.